# problem with php writing to a file. broken code. help!

Tags: php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("****") or die(mysql_error());
// Make a MySQL Connection

$query = "SELECT * FROM sk";     
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$myFile = 'sitemap-sk.txt';
$myContent ="";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $myContent .= "<url><loc>/".$row['id']."-".$row['company_name'].".html</loc>
                     <changefreq>monthly</changefreq></url>\n\r";

}
file_put_contents($myFile, $myContent); 

?>
```

Trying to get this data to write to `sitemap-sk.txt` but not having any luck

Comment: nothing. page just loads and does nothing.

Comment: You mean your sitemap-sk.txt is empty ?

Comment: of i take everything out and replace $myContent .= with echo its print and returns all values.

Comment: yes sitemap-sk.txt is an empty writable file.

Comment: 99% I/O file's problem are related to the file permission. Make sure the webserver (Apache ?) can write into the destination folder

Comment: try displaying all errors and notices by adding this directly behind the `<?php`:  `error_reporting (E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it works:

```
$myFile = 'sitemap-sk.txt';
$fp=fopen($myFile,'a+')

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    fwrite( $fp, "<url><loc>/".$row['id']."-".$row['company_name'].".html</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq></url>\n\r");

}
fclose($fp);
```

**EDIT :** 
**Try This and say result to me :**

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $content[] = "<url><loc>/".$row['id']."-".$row['company_name'].".html</loc><changefreq>monthly</changefreq></url>\n\r";

    }

var_dump($content);
```

Comment: then it must be a permission problem. on what system are you running your script?

Comment: Is your error reporting on ?No error displayed ?set error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: hm. try the full path for your file `$myFile = '/var/www/yoursite/sitemap-sk.txt';`

Comment: @Fender: He said file created but it's empty

Comment: oh... strange. so the vardump will be interesting

Answer (score 0):

Trying your code without the MySQL part worked flawlessly in mi case.
That is:

```
$myFile = 'sitemap-sk.txt';
$myContent ="some test content";
file_put_contents($myFile, $myContent);
```

Because of the behaviour you mention, I think you may have a MySQL problem.
Let me explain: you've put **...or die(mysql_error());** in every line that has a MySQL statement. This causes the script to terminate abruptly, without output, if it encounters an error. So, the script actually never fetchs data from your database.

You should debug which line is causing the **die()** to trigger.
I recommend you remove the **...or die(mysql_error());** calls and use something like (from the top of my head):

```
if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
    do stuff
}
else {
    echo "query error\n";
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: I tried that and no errors. Also error message display is enabled with no errors. If i change the output to echo it displays all the proper data.

Comment: If you could create a file, then it's not a file permissions issue.
Could you please do a paste of the data you mentioned?